# Problem with autoextender poisitioning asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

Can anyone help with this issue i have with the auto complete extender for asp.net 3.5.

Basically when i type the text into the texbox, the autocomplete extender does not appear underneath the textbox. It appears sometimes on top or underneath the textbox.

Is there a way i can fix the position of the autoextender popup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use a very old autoextender code.

Update your code from : http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475